# what does \$X(z) \pm X(-z)\$ mean?

Tags: signal-processing

If a system's output is \$X(z)+X(-z)\$ or \$X(z)-X(-z)\$, what does it do to the input \$X(z)\$? 
I know what happens in time-domain, but not pretty sure about the change in frequency-domain.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know what happens to the frequency spectrum, you need to evaluate the output on the unit circle \$z=e^{j\omega}\$. Since \$-z=-e^{j\omega}=e^{j(\omega+\pi)}\$, the output spectrum is

$$Y(e^{j\omega})=X(e^{j\omega})+X(e^{j(\omega+\pi)})$$

That means that the output spectrum is the sum of the original input spectrum and a shifted version of the input spectrum, where the amount of shift equals \$\pi\$ (i.e. half the sampling frequency).